# How to combine two interfaces and make all of its fields optional?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have two interfaces **that cannot be modified**:

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
interface User {
  username: string;
  password: string;
}
```

I want to combine them into just one: `Player`

```
// please, modify this code accordingly

interface Player extends Person, User {
  device: string
}
```

where `name` and `age` are optional.

So, if I do this:

```
const member: Player = {
  username: 'bill.gates',
  password: 'M1cRoS0ft',
  device: 'PSP',
}
```

then I don't get an error because: `name` and `age` are missing.

Here you have the [Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=20&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyyIcAthAFzIZhSgDmA3EcnA1SQK5kBG0LAL4ECoSLEQoAqhmj5WXWVFIVqteiGasADnAwYA7ligATNXUZCRY6PCRoANnACeciAA9IIExjSYcADTIMnKExCYQAG7ASOYaDATCBAg4tMgUfNDUqE6uUMgAvPLEitAqnADkvMAODgB0DHCQGBUBOnqGxmbIFQCyAIwIAEpYAMoADDBgrawR0bE9qKOoM8JAA).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [the native utility type `Partial<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialt) to construct an interface where its properties are optional, then extend from it.

That would give the following code :

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

interface User {
  username: string;
  password: string;
}

interface Player extends Partial<Person>, User {
  device: string;
}

const member: Player = {
  username: 'bill.gates',
  password: 'M1cRoS0ft',
  device: 'PSP',
}
```

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=20&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyyIcAthAFzIZhSgDmA3EcnA1SQK5kBG0LAL4ECoSLEQoAqhmj5WXWVFIVqteiGasADnAwYA7ligATNXUZCRY6PCRoANnACeciAA9IIExjRwoYMBwDgA86FDYIAB8ADTIMnKExCYQAG7ASOYaWsIECDi0yBR80NSoTq5QyAC88sSK0CqcAOS8wA4OAHQMcJAYzTE6eobGZsjNALIAjAgASlgAygAMMGADrCnpmeOoC6jrwkA)